# testflight the app token for this app was not detected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, testflight

Recently I have added some devices on Developer portal and try to upload the new build on test flight but getting this error 
["the app token for this app was not detected"](http://s13.postimg.org/6a1m79u3r/test_flight.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that TestFlight are presenting this message either in error or to push their SDK.

I can confirm that if you 'Ignore and Continue' everything works as per usual. I have verified that beta testers are able to install and open the app.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check you token from `testflight` app
2. Add device identifier for test flight

   // In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

   [TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];

   [TestFlight takeOff:@"9e5f8b26-358f-4a0e-b9c2-186d932b1187"];

Answer (score 0):

Login to the [Dashboard](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/). Select the app you want to upload. Click on App Token on the left menu. You can get your app token from there. Then download the SDK. Follow [SDK Installation Guide](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/doc/) to integrate TestFlight to your app.

Comment: I dont want to integrate the sdk because its running fine without the sdk previously.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Testflight.
2. Go to Apps
3. Go to your app name
4. Click on the down-arrow beside your app name in the top-right corner.
5. Go to edit info
6. Check the Token appears there
7. Compare the Token with your app token.

If they are same. Then wait for the cashes from Testflight. Otherwise correct those.

**In case if you haven't integrated testflight sdk into your app.**

Delete your app from testflight and upload it again.

To delete app checkout following snap[image].

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: I have not implemented the Testflight sdk in my App. I think its not necessary to implement the sdk because its running fine previously without the sdk. I just added some new devices and got this error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem; we don't use the SDK either and simply distribute beta builds through TestFlight. Never seen this message previously.

Looks like we can just hit 'ignore and continue' though...